# How can I overwrite the data of an existing component in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am attempting to write a webapp that monitors the price of various cryptocurrency as an exercise for learning Angular.

At the moment I have managed to return values from the API every 5 seconds and display the new data on screen. The issue is that when an API call is made the new data is used to create new components. Which means that 3 new components are created every 5 seconds. Instead, I want the existing components to be overwritten with their new values.

To be able to do this I feel like I'll have to create the components first instead of using the `*ngFor` directive to create them dynamically. But I'm not too sure how I go about this.

HomeComponent Template

```
<div class="container ticker-row-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <app-ticker-row *ngFor="let detail of cryptoDetails" [cryptoDetail]="detail"></app-ticker-row>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

HomeComponent Class

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  cryptos: string[] = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum', 'litecoin']
  cryptoDetails: CryptoDetail[];

  constructor(private cryptoService: CryptoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cryptoDetails = new Array();
    this.getCryptoData();
    const source = interval(5000).subscribe(val => this.getCryptoData());
  }

  getCryptoData(){
    console.log("get crypto")
    for(let crypto of this.cryptos){
      this.cryptoService.getCryptoInfo(crypto).subscribe(res => {
        let data = res.data;
        let cryptoDetail = new CryptoDetail(data.id, data.rateUsd, data.symbol);
        this.cryptoDetails.push(cryptoDetail);

      })
    }
  }
}
```

TickerRowComponent Template

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">{{cryptoDetail.symbol}}</div>
  <div class="col-4">{{cryptoDetail.id}}</div>
  <div class="col-4">{{cryptoDetail.rate}}</div>
</div>
```

TickerRowComponent Class

```
export class TickerRowComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() cryptoDetail: CryptoDetail

  currentRate: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentRate = this.cryptoDetail.rate;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are subscribing your cryptoService after every 5 seconds you are pushing the new crypto detail to the cryptoDetails array thus it keeps the previous crypto details along with the new crypto details. Instead what you can do is to remove the previous values from the array inside your getCryptoData function :

```
getCryptoData(){
    this.cryptoDetails = [];
    console.log("get crypto")
    for(let crypto of this.cryptos){
      this.cryptoService.getCryptoInfo(crypto).subscribe(res => {
        let data = res.data;
        let cryptoDetail = new CryptoDetail(data.id, data.rateUsd, data.symbol);
        this.cryptoDetails.push(cryptoDetail);

      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works well, thanks. The only problem now is that when the page refreshes with the new data there is a blink between the old data being deleted and the new data being used. Is there anyway I can stop this blink?

Comment: I think blink can be removed by using a loader, show the loader before and then remove it once you get the data, I can think of this to make good user experience.

Comment: But the data refreshes every 5 seconds, meaning it blinks every 5 seconds.

Comment: Might be yes, user can see something is updating.